# Get list of all files in a directory inside assets

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have a folder in assets called "myFolder" and inside that I have a bunch of files. How do I get a list of the filenames of all files inside "myFolder"?

I'm fairly new to Android programming, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [AssetManager.list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String))

```
AssetManager man = context.getAssets();
String[] files = man.list("folder1");
```

Supposing you have this folder inside your assets folder

```
folder1
    ├── one.txt
    ├── three.txt
    └── two.txt
```

Then with that code you will get an array containing "one.txt", "two.txt" and "three.txt".

Comment: AssetManager instead of AssetsManager

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
File folder = new File("path/to/myFolder");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (files[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("file " + files[i].getName());
  } else if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("dir " + files[i].getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect for anything in Android, let alone assets. Never hardcode paths, and assets are not files on the Android filesystem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I missed the "assets" part. I thought he wanted to get the listing of files of the internal filesystem or sd card

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 http://android.okhelp.cz/get-assets-folder-files-to-array-of-strings-android-example/
```

Above is the link where you can find how to get the list of all files of asset.

Comment: This is for files on external storage. The question is about assets.